# How can ROS communicate with my microcontroller?

Tags: ros, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some recent questions have shown an interest in how ROS can be used to run a motor or read a sensor on a custom robot. Many hobby robots have one or more microcontrollers that interface with the robot hardware. These microcontrollers should be able to communicate using a serial connection to a robot mounted laptop running ROS.

The avr_bridge is a sophisticated approach, but it requires a larger AVR processor and C++ code development on the microcontroller which may not be available in some circumstances. Is there a simpler alternative?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10114/how-can-ros-communicate-with-my-microcontroller?/) by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-31**:
I have an ATmega16 that is already 85% full with ISR's, servo control and sensor processing. Some AVR's use a variant of Basic for programming. Some people are loyal to PIC microprocessors. I would like to try avr_bridge on my ATmega128 for a future project.

**Comment by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) on 2011-05-31**:
@Bart - Can you provide a bit more explanation on when avr_bridge isn't suitable, perhaps chips you've had an issue with? I've been using it with the Arduino Duemilanove (ATmega328) and have been quite happy with its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple approach is to write a ROS node that can read/write text messages exchanged with the microcontroller over a serial port and convert these serial messages to ROS style std_msgs/String messages. A separate ROS node can then be written to convert the simple text messages to specific ROS message formats (cmd_vel, odom, etc) based on whatever message protocol was defined for the exchange with the microcontroller.

Attached below is the source for code that I used for this purpose. There is nothing original in the code, but it may be helpful to someone new to ROS and Unix/Linux serial communication. Posting this type of a listing may be a bit unconventional for this site as short answers are generally preferred. Hopefully no one is offended. I would be interested in hearing if there are other successful approaches to the problem.

```
/*                                                                                                                       
 * Copyright (c) 2010, Willow Garage, Inc.                                                                               
 * All rights reserved.                                                                                                  
 *                                                                                                                       
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without                                                    
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:                                           
 *                                                                                                                       
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright                                                  
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.                                                   
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright                                               
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the                                             
 *       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.                                            
 *     * Neither the name of the Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its                                                
 *       contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from                                            
 *       this software without specific prior written permission.                                                        
 *                                                                                                                       
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"                                           
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE                                             
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE                                            
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE                                              
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR                                                   
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF                                                  
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS                                              
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN                                               
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)                                               
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE                                            
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                                                                                           
 */

//r2Serial.cpp

// communicate via RS232 serial with a remote uController. 
// communicate with ROS using String type messages.
// subscribe to command messages from ROS
// publish command responses to ROS

// program parameters - ucontroller# (0,1), serial port, baud rate

//Thread main
//  Subscribe to ROS String messages and send as commands to uController
//Thread receive
//  Wait for responses from uController and publish as a ROS messages


#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_BAUDRATE 19200
#define DEFAULT_SERIALPORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

//Global data
FILE *fpSerial = NULL;   //serial port file pointer
ros::Publisher ucResponseMsg;
ros::Subscriber ucCommandMsg;
int ucIndex;          //ucontroller index number


//Initialize serial port, return file descriptor
FILE *serialInit(char * port, int baud)
{
  int BAUD = 0;
  int fd = -1;
  struct termios newtio;
  FILE *fp = NULL;

 //Open the serial port as a file descriptor for low level configuration
 // read/write, not controlling terminal for process,
  fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
  if ( fd<0 )
  {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Could not open serial device %s",port);
    return fp;
  }

  // set up new settings
  memset(&newtio, 0,sizeof(newtio));
  newtio.c_cflag =  CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;  //no parity, 1 stop bit

  newtio.c_iflag = IGNCR;    //ignore CR, other options off
  newtio.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;  //ignore break condition

  newtio.c_oflag = 0;        //all options off

  newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;     //process input as lines

  // activate new settings
  tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
  //Look up appropriate baud rate constant
  switch (baud)
  {
     case 38400:
     default:
        BAUD = B38400;
        break;
     case 19200:
        BAUD  = B19200;
        break;
     case 9600:
        BAUD  = B9600;
        break;
     case 4800:
        BAUD  = B4800;
        break;
     case 2400:
        BAUD  = B2400;
        break;
     case 1800:
        BAUD  = B1800;
        break;
     case 1200:
        BAUD  = B1200;
        break;
  }  //end of switch baud_rate
  if (cfsetispeed(&newtio, BAUD) < 0 || cfsetospeed(&newtio, BAUD) < 0)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Failed to set serial baud rate: %d", baud);
    close(fd);
    return NULL;
  }
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);
  tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

  //Open file as a standard I/O stream
  fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");
  if (!fp) {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Failed to open serial stream %s", port);
    fp = NULL;
  }
  return fp;
} //serialInit


//Process ROS command message, send to uController
void ucCommandCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_DEBUG("uc%dCommand: %s", ucIndex, msg->data.c_str());
  fprintf(fpSerial, "%s", msg->data.c_str()); //appends newline
} //ucCommandCallback


//Receive command responses from robot uController
//and publish as a ROS message
void *rcvThread(void *arg)
{
  int rcvBufSize = 200;
  char ucResponse[rcvBufSize];   //response string from uController
  char *bufPos;
  std_msgs::String msg;
  std::stringstream ss;

  ROS_INFO("rcvThread: receive thread running");

  while (ros::ok()) {
    bufPos = fgets(ucResponse, rcvBufSize, fpSerial);
    if (bufPos != NULL) {
      ROS_DEBUG("uc%dResponse: %s", ucIndex, ucResponse);
      msg.data = ucResponse;
      ucResponseMsg.publish(msg);
    }
  }
  return NULL;
} //rcvThread


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char port[20];    //port name
  int baud;     //baud rate 

  char topicSubscribe[20];
  char topicPublish[20];

  pthread_t rcvThrID;   //receive thread ID
  int err;

  //Initialize ROS
  ros::init(argc, argv, "r2SerialDriver");
  ros::NodeHandle rosNode;
  ROS_INFO("r2Serial starting");

  //Open and initialize the serial port to the uController
  if (argc > 1) {
    if(sscanf(argv[1],"%d", &ucIndex)==1) {
      sprintf(topicSubscribe, "uc%dCommand",ucIndex);
      sprintf(topicPublish, "uc%dResponse",ucIndex);
    }
    else {
      ROS_ERROR("ucontroller index parameter invalid");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    strcpy(topicSubscribe, "uc0Command");
    strcpy(topicPublish, "uc0Response");
  }

  strcpy(port, DEFAULT_SERIALPORT);
  if (argc > 2)
     strcpy(port, argv[2]);

  baud = DEFAULT_BAUDRATE;
  if (argc > 3) {
    if(sscanf(argv[3],"%d", &baud)!=1) {
      ROS_ERROR("ucontroller baud rate parameter invalid");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  ROS_INFO("connection initializing (%s) at %d baud", port, baud);
   fpSerial = serialInit(port, baud);
  if (!fpSerial )
  {
    ROS_ERROR("unable to create a new serial port");
    return 1;
  }
  ROS_INFO("serial connection successful");

  //Subscribe to ROS messages
  ucCommandMsg = rosNode.subscribe(topicSubscribe, 100, ucCommandCallback);

  //Setup to publish ROS messages
  ucResponseMsg = rosNode.advertise<std_msgs::String>(topicPublish, 100);

  //Create receive thread
  err = pthread_create(&rcvThrID, NULL, rcvThread, NULL);
  if (err != 0) {
    ROS_ERROR("unable to create receive thread");
    return 1;
  }

  //Process ROS messages and send serial commands to uController
  ros::spin();

  fclose(fpSerial);
  ROS_INFO("r2Serial stopping");
  return 0;
}
```

I can also offer a simple launch file that interfaces to two microcontrollers using two serial connections:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="r2SerialDriver" type="r2Serial" name="r2Serial0" args="0 /dev/ttyUSB0 19200" output="screen" >
  <remap from="ucCommand" to="uc0Command" />
  <remap from="ucResponse" to="uc0Response" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="r2SerialDriver" type="r2Serial" name="r2Serial1" args="1 /dev/ttyUSB1 19200" output="screen" >
  <remap from="ucCommand" to="uc1Command" />
  <remap from="ucResponse" to="uc1Response" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-22**:
Interesting, but a lot of my serial stuff is send a message and receive a response back. Instead of separate publish/subscribes have you tried a service? That seems like it would work nicely for this.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-10-22**:
@Bart Do you have a python version for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be exactly what I need... I think... but may be a little over my head so I will likely have a few questions regarding how to set this up.  I'm using an arm attached to a BS2.  I have a Roomba platform (that will have the arm attached) being controlled via a laptop running Ubuntu/ROS with web based control via php pages.  I would like to use ROS to control the arm as well but I'm unsure of some of the basics.  I have the ARM working through the Basic Stamp and I'm able to control the arm via the laptop keyboard... should I keep the BS2 microcontroller and send serial commands using the code above (if so, I'll have other questions)... or, is it better (even feasible...) to bypass the microcontroller and send commands directly to the arm using ROS?  I think this is possible, but I'm a novice and need help connecting the dots.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

---

Originally posted by [kleekru](https://answers.ros.org/users/987/kleekru/) with karma: 71 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-22**:
Agree, Bart's answer is cool, but is over kill for a beginner. If you pull out the thread stuff, but keep the serial setup, you can make something like the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) that talks to a serial port in the while loop.